# Regular Expression for validating any kind of letters

Tags: .net, regex, validation

In my application I need to validate english characters as well as spanish characters like

ã
   à
   ç
    z
    Ë
    Ç

So any one please help me to validating this kind letters .

Comment: From [tag:regex] tag: "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: ok next time I put a question I will make sure about the tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `\p{L}`, describes the class of Unicode letter characters.
You may need to use extra flags depending on languages .

This is how you may do in **python** for example

```
import re
s = u"Sãràth S Pillai"
regex  = r'[\p{L}]*'
result = re.search(regex,s,re.UNICODE)
```

Here is sample code in **C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"[\p{L}]*");
        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches("Sãràth S Pillài");
        foreach (Match match in matches) {
            try {
                Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
            }
            catch { }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using C# with mvc4 and I am trying this using data annotations

Comment: @Abi it works for c# also just pasred some code here

Comment: But when I using this regex in data annotations it will not be working                                                                      [RegularExpression(@"[\p{L}\w]*", ErrorMessage = "Please Enter correct format")]

Comment: What is the error ?.  I am not a C# develper this is the first C# code i have written :D

Comment: @Abi could you please expain it will not be working.Does it mean it will fail to match or it will match invalid also . What is a sample string that you need  to verify

Comment: I also use your sample string when enter the string it will show the error message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134150/discussion-between-sarathsp-and-abi).

Comment: Why are you using `\w` in the character class? `\p[L}` is enough to match all letters and OP doesn't want to match digits or underscore.